# WooCommerce Stock number display

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stock

I've been trying to get rid of our exact stock numbers on product pages on our wordpress/woocommerce website. Ideally it shows In stock, Only 1 or 2 left in stock when theres only 1 or 2 available, or just sold out. I've tried many of the code snippets found here on stack overflow but none of them seem to change anything. Also the standard woocommerce settings at Products > Inventory to don't show any stock numbers doesn't do anything. On the front end it keeps showing Availability: Exact stock amount. Can anyone help me out?

Adding these kind of snippets to my child theme's functions.php or even in a code snippet plugin doesn't seem to do anything for me:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    
    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce');
    }
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Comment: So you want to display available qty in single product page

Comment: It shows the exact quantities now but i want it to just show In stock or Sold out. Ideally also just add 2 or 1 in stock when that's the case. Or even just Almost sold out when it's low on stock.

Comment: Did u tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355379/display-always-stock-status-without-quantity-in-woocommerce answer

Comment: Yeah i've tried changing the woocommerce settings and both those pieces of code but it doesn't do anything..

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use `woocommerce_get_availability_text` instead of `woocommerce_get_availability`. This filters only the availability text and is called after `woocommerce_get_availability`.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'set_custom_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function set_custom_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability = __( 'Available!', 'woocommerce' );
    } elseif ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability = __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

If the above code doesn't do anything, test if the filter is being called by using the `die()` function. This will stop the execution of any code that comes after it and prints whatever string you put in between the parentheses:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'set_custom_availability_text_test', 10, 2 );
function set_custom_availability_text_test( $availability, $product ) {
    die('Filter is called');
}
```

So if the filter is called correctly your page should render up to the availabitly text and display 'Filter is called' where the availabilty text should be. If nothing happens this means the filter isn't called. So then check if your functions.php is being loaded, or use a plugin like Code Snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortionately this still doesn't do anything. It keeps showing the exact stock numbers like always. Any other tips are more than welcome!

Comment: Have you made sure the filter is called by adding the `die()`?

Comment: I've tried the updated code you posted but still nothing. adding that die() at the top is just to test things or should that also possibly impact the result?

Comment: I've fully updated my answer, please check if the filter is being called at all.

Comment: I've tested it and the filter is called correctly. The pages shows exactly as you said saying Filter is called and not loading anything below it. When using the actual filter like you posted even with 25, 2. it's still not changing the stock quantities to the set names.

Comment: Can you try to run this with just WooCommerce active? And see if it works then? If so, then a plugin is overwriting this filter. You can turn on your other plugins one by one, and test in between, to see which plugin overwrites the filter. Then investigate from there on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet help you to change text for all product or particular one:

```
  <?php
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability',1,2);
    function wcs_custom_get_availability($availability,$_product ) {
       global $product;
        switch($_product->slug){
            // Enter product slug for case
            case "test-1":
                // text for in stock mode 
                if($_product->manage_stock = true){
                        $availability['availability'] = str_replace($availability['availability'],"Enter your custom text here $_product->stock_quantity",$availability['availability']);
                }
                // text for out of stock mode 
                if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
                         $availability['availability'] = __('Enter your custom text here', 'woocommerce');
                }
    
                break;
                
            case "test2":
                if($_product->manage_stock = true){
                        $availability['availability'] = str_replace($availability['availability'],"Enter your custom text here $_product->stock_quantity",$availability['availability']);
                }
                if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
                         $availability['availability'] = __(' Enter your custom text here', 'woocommerce');
                }
                break;
                
            case "test3":
                if($_product->manage_stock = true){
                        $availability['availability'] = str_replace($availability['availability'],"Enter your custom text here $_product->stock_quantity نفر",$availability['availability']);
                }
                if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
                         $availability['availability'] = __(' Enter your custom text here', 'woocommerce');
                }
                break;
        }
    
    
        return $availability;
    }
```